# Replacing a blobstore file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, kml, python-2.7

I serve static KML from the blobstore as a file that I saved to the blobstore

```
class KMLHandler2(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):

    def get(self):
        resource = 'AMIfv965WtxAc_rWOVjSSx423_oe6f-g5obWYNKX5scg-1gqvISyaZCnv6lRaqro2wOVNOogttyMOylFLsRYZ3Y9UYIe-A69vAt4pdJB2-SHUcdVEM2v0XVLxzT3fTlxwXQVhzmsHPwALH_rCSFIvmYcuV37asVD0Q'
        resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
        self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

This works but I want to update the file regularly. The file is generated from `/list.kml` so I could read it directly from there but then it times out so my plan is to make my first appenine task that reads the file from `list.kml` and writes it to the blobstore with that same key but how do I do that when the only examples are how to create a new file? I have the places in the code where I update the data layer and it' not very often. Can you suggest how I should do when I update the file? I suppose I want the key and id to be the same and replace the old blob instead of writing a new and refreshing the key. Can you help me? The app engine docs say how to write a blobstore file but only a new one, I don't know how to edit or replace a file given it's key and I think that is what I need to do as a task or a cron job so I ask for your help.

I could make a handler like in the docs but that is for creating a file, not modifying / replacing one:

```
class CreateKMLHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # Create the file
        file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream')

        # Open the file and write to it
        with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
          f.write('data')

        # Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.
        files.finalize(file_name)

        # Get the file's blob key
        blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
```

Thanks

### Update

I try this code to make a new file but it get a deadline error applicationerror 5 which I suppose is a timeout issue. How can I make it a task instead?

```
class CreateKMLHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # Create the file
        file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream')

        url = 'http://montaoproject.appspot.com/list.kml'

        result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
        if not result.content:
            return

        # Open the file and write to it
        with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
          f.write(result.content)

        # Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.
        files.finalize(file_name)

        # Get the file's blob key
        blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
        self.out.write(blob_key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once blobs have been written, they can not be changed (only read or deleted). You could use datastore entities to keep track of the current blob key associated with a given KML 'document'.

You might also be interested in the Cloud Storage API ( http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview.html ), which allows you to overwrite 'bucket' objects by creating new objects with the same name.

Comment: OK I'll just make a new blob then. Thank you for the info.